# Cancelable kriskowal q promise request

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, q

Consider the following code snippets

```
function method(){
    asynMethod();
}

function asynMethod(){
    q.when([]).then(function(){
        //do something
    })
}
```

Whenever `method` is called it call the `asyncMethod` to perform some stuff asynchronously. If `method` is called twice quickly, sometimes the second request will resolve before the first request. Now I want to cancel out any existing calls(q) sent through `asyncMethod` prior to calling it again.

Thanks.

Comment: you can't really cancel anything. what is the async method actually doing

Comment: async method bind result to an observable property

Comment: You should make a more realisitic sample or explanation. Why do you implement the second method as async? What for? Why? How do you invoke it? Why can it be invoke many times? Adding some information to this question will make it possible to answer it.

Comment: https://github.com/domenic/last

Comment: You won't be able "cancel" a request once made, but you could ensure that any subsequent call is not made if it has already been called? Like @JotaBe said... difficult to say without the 'What for' and 'Why' etc...

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminGruenbaum last.js lib helped